# Inserting Excel file as an image in email using Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2010

Yesterday at work, I was sent an email from a co-worker containing an embedded Excel 2010 object.  I have Outlook 2010, as does the sender. Instead of being able to work in the Excel object or make edits, it seems to have attached to the message as an image.  How do you get it to send so the recipient can edit it?  The email was in html format.

The sender prepared the email by copying from Excel, then pasting special into Outlook as an Excel object.

We tried sending a new message in rich text format, and when done this way, it lets me copy the data in the spreadsheet, but you still can't open it within the email as if it's in Excel.  We also enabled "Adjust formatting when pasting from Microsoft Excel" in 'Use Smart Cut and Paste' within Outlook mail editor options, and that didn't work.  Any idea how to fix this?  We both have Windows 7 Pro also.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you ever successfully done this before? Have you tried sending a different XLS from a different email account and see how that one behaves?

Comment: I don't think it can be done.  It seems that when you send an Excel object this way, the recipient can't edit it.  It only delivers as an image, or plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the recipient to be able to work with the content as a fully functional Excel worksheet, you need to send it as a saved Excel file using the 'Attach File' functionality:

[image]

If the rest of the workbook has information in it that you don't want sent, you'll have to copy just the data you want into a new workbook and send that.

Embedding Excel data into anything (email, Word doc, whatever) is fraught with problems and best avoided.